# I want to dynamically show 2 images in MFC CDialog dialog box. Can somebody please give me a hint on how to do it?

Tags: image, mfc, cdialog

I am able to show 2 images by opening 2 dialog boxes, but I want to show both of them in the same dialog box. The images will keep on changing

Comment: How do you show the image? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way of doing this is as follows:

- add the images as Bitmap resources to the project;
- add a picture control to the dialog for each bitmap, position and size as you want it;
- set the image property of the picture controls to point to the bitmap resource.

If this way is too static or not how you want to do it, then you'll need to update your question to be more specific.

Comment: I would like the images to be changed dynamically. I have tried adding one more Dialog Box, but it is opening one more window

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to invalidate two different rectangles of the DC on which you're drawing. Maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568559/displaying-image-in-mfc-method-that-is-not-onpaint) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885997/dividing-a-cdialog-in-two-areas-with-different-backgrounds-picture-of-the-objec) will guide you further.

Comment: Thanks, the links were really helful